# Can the empty set be the image of a function on $\mathbb{N}$?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I cannot find any example of function $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ of which we can say that 
$$
f(\mathbb{N})=\emptyset
$$
Does there exists any?

Comment: If $D_f=\emptyset$

Comment: By definition, the set $f(\mathbb{N})$ contains each $f(n)$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: You say "an empty set" but note that there is only one empty set: "**the** empty set."

Comment: Not sure that this counts as a duplicate.  The other question was a technical question of why the axiom of specification fails to claim "$F\subset A\times \emptyset$ so that $F$ is a function" exists and required a far more technical and obtuse than this rather practical question.  That's my two cents.  But I'm certainly not going to vote to reopen.

Answer (score 17):

No.  By definition of $f:A \to B$, then for every $a\in A$ then $f(a)$ must exist and $f(a) \in B$.  So if $A$ is not empty then $f(A)$ is not empty (although it can have a few as only one element.)

However it is possible that $A$ is empty in which case $f(A)$ is (obviously) also empty.

$f: \emptyset \to B$ is the empty function in this case.

=====

Or to put it really simple $f(1)$ has to be in the image so the image can't be empty.

Comment: You should say "No if the domain is non-empty.". As you've clearly proven in the last two lines the answer is "Yes".

Comment: The OP states that the domain is $\mathbb{N}$...

Comment: @Ister "You should say 'No if the domain is non-empty.'" Do you really  think it needs to be proven that $\Bbb N$ is non-empty?

Comment: @Vincent was your comment addressed at me or Ister.  If at me, well, ... so?  I've shown it is false for any non-empty domain.  $\Bbb N$ is a non-empty domain.  So the answer to the OP's question is "no".

Comment: @fleablood the comment was directed at Ister.

Comment: My bad. I missed the part that domain is $\mathbb{N}$

Answer (score 9):

There is no such function: in particular, the only function whose image is the empty set is the empty function, whose domain is also the empty set. In particular, $f(\mathbb{N})$ cannot be the empty set, because contains $f(1)$.

Answer (score 7):

Well, the definition state that for any x natural number there exists a uniquely determined natural number y such as f(x)=y. Since f(N) has no elements, it means that there doesn’t exist any y such as f(x)=y. Contradiction! So such functions do not exist :) The image of a function has at least one element as Df has at least 1 element.

Answer (score 3):

Since for every $a\in \mathbb{N}$ the $f(a)$ is also in $\mathbb{N}$ we see that $f(\mathbb{N})\ne \emptyset $ so there is no such function.

Answer (score 1):

This case is not possible since, by definition of *range* of a function, $f(a)$ should belong to the codomain for each $a$ in the domain.